# Pass object in JSON, or in var (Drag and drop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drag-and-drop

Just a little question, i don't know which one is the best using Drag and Drop system.

Is it better to :

- use setData and getData to pass a javascript object ? (Using JSON conversion, of course, setData only pass String)
- Or using a temporary var ? (instantiated in dragStart).

Ty !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use data() to link the javascript object to the element being dragged - see https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/. You don't have to use JSON conversion in this case or a temporary var.